# Alexa's On-Page SEO Checker does not seem to process parameters passed in the URL?

Tags: seo, alexa

I have a website which displays information based on the parameters passed to the page. For example, page URL is: `www.mysite.com?p=ZZZ`, then I pull a value from database, based on the value of `p`, say `ZZ Title` and dispaly it in the `h1` tag. The rendered HTML look like this: `<h1> ZZ Title </h1>`.

I am using Alexa for analyzing my site for SEO. When I analyse this page using Alexa's **On-Page SEO Checker**, it says that I must populate `<h1>` tag and Alexa display result like this: `<h1> </h1>` (shows empty tag).

When I use a variable in `h1` which does not depend on the URL parameters, then Alexa have no problem and the `h1` tag is properly populated.

My questions are:

1. Anyone have experience such behavior. I am curious if anything wrong with my code?
2. Is Alexa's On-Page SEO Checker ignoring URL parameters?

Comment: This is because Alexa is pure junk. Stop looking at it! Please. Come here for your SEO advice. We have real exerts here. Honest! Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working with Alexa's support on the issue, it turned out that this was a bug in the Alexa On-Page SEO Checker tool. They have fixed it now.